# Get Value of JSON Sting in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

First of all thank you in advance. I am trying to retrieve the following values from the JSON string below using PowerShell but am having issues.

```
ScheduleTitle,
Title,
Environment and Title
Resolution,
Width,
Height
```

JSON:

```
{"Id":"d52fb00e-8736-448c-a496-96db6bc2eb43","ScheduleId":"275726dc-09f2-4869-b1a0-54c71ef6a093","ScheduleTitle":"Resolution Testing","RunType":"RunNow","Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:19.2039685","AutomationRunItems":[{"Id":"f7b731fb-cd96-4003-b95c-ef1594f1c86e","AutomationRunId":"d52fb00e-8736-448c-a496-96db6bc2eb43","Status":"Done","Case":{"Id":"c8a0b939-54ba-4b98-8ca9-101093aec26f","Title":"Resolution Test"},"Environment":{"Id":"e1783fb5-4001-45d0-9971-b49c31b374ab","Title":"Se Chrome"},"Keyframes":[{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:03.0685609","Elapsed":"00:00:00","Level":"Info","Status":"Connecting","BlockId":"78c198ac-b61f-40eb-b1d9-e706546f2be3","LogMessage":"Connecting to Se Chrome: Selenium Grid (localhost:5559) on Chrome with size 1280x1024"},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:03.0685609","Elapsed":"00:00:00.0000003","Level":"Info","Status":"Connected","BlockId":"78c198ac-b61f-40eb-b1d9-e706546f2be3","LogMessage":"Connected"},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:03.0685609","Elapsed":"00:00:00.0000015","Level":"Info","Status":"Running","BlockId":"78c198ac-b61f-40eb-b1d9-e706546f2be3","LogMessage":"Running"},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:03.0695642","Elapsed":"00:00:00.0003729","Level":"Trace","Status":"Running","BlockId":"78c198ac-b61f-40eb-b1d9-e706546f2be3","LogMessage":"Block is executing."},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:03.5713896","Elapsed":"00:00:00.5020154","Level":"Trace","Status":"Running","BlockId":"78c198ac-b61f-40eb-b1d9-e706546f2be3","LogMessage":"Block is executed."},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:03.5713896","Elapsed":"00:00:00.5021370","Level":"Trace","Status":"Running","BlockId":"302f21b8-a279-48ce-9338-580a97c930fd","LogMessage":"Block is executing."},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:06.9793063","Elapsed":"00:00:03.9107459","Level":"Info","Status":"Running","BlockId":"302f21b8-a279-48ce-9338-580a97c930fd","LogMessage":"Chrome was successfully started"},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:09.4641639","Elapsed":"00:00:06.3955903","Level":"Info","Status":"Running","BlockId":"302f21b8-a279-48ce-9338-580a97c930fd","LogMessage":"Chrome loaded url https://dev.bamapplication.com/app/starke/npr/3BF6DA09C1/wizard"},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:09.7604882","Elapsed":"00:00:06.6925088","Level":"Trace","Status":"Running","BlockId":"302f21b8-a279-48ce-9338-580a97c930fd","LogMessage":"Block is executed."},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:09.7604882","Elapsed":"00:00:06.6926471","Level":"Trace","Status":"Running","BlockId":"26382d5d-60a6-4343-b934-265c4e97186d","LogMessage":"Block is executing."},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:10.4639126","Elapsed":"00:00:07.3954580","Level":"Warning","Status":"Running","BlockId":"26382d5d-60a6-4343-b934-265c4e97186d","LogMessage":"Web screenshot is saved"},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:10.7666916","Elapsed":"00:00:07.6982198","Level":"Trace","Status":"Running","BlockId":"26382d5d-60a6-4343-b934-265c4e97186d","LogMessage":"Block is executed."},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:10.7666916","Elapsed":"00:00:07.6983727","Level":"Trace","Status":"Running","BlockId":"161e621f-bb7a-4f42-a5f1-67e07d1432f4","LogMessage":"Block is executing."},{"Timestamp":"2017-08-01T04:52:11.7677637","Elapsed":"00:00:08.6992111","Level":"Info","Status":"Done","BlockId":"161e621f-bb7a-4f42-a5f1-67e07d1432f4","LogMessage":"Case is stopped."}],"Resolution":{"Width":1280,"Height":1024},"Elapsed":"00:00:08.6992111","CreatedAt":"2017-08-01T04:52:19.2039685","ModifiedAt":"2017-08-01T04:52:19.2039685"}],"ProjectId":"275726dc-09f2-4869-b1a0-54c71ef6a093","ExecutionTotalTime":"00:00:08.6992111","FailedCount":0,"PassedCount":0,"DoneCount":1,"CreatedAt":"2017-08-01T04:52:03.0685609"}
```

Code:

```
Param( [string]$result, [string]$rootPath )
try{ 
    $json = $result
    $parsed = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
    $output= ''
    foreach ($line in $parsed | Get-Member) { 
        Write-Output $parsed.$($line.Resolution).property1 
        Write-Output $parsed.$($line.Resolution).property2 
        $output += $parsed.$($line.Resolution).property1 + " " + $parsed.$($line.Resolution).property1 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask a question. How are you trying to retrieve the values is not specified.

Comment: Put it in the question.

Comment: The properties you want need to be better defined. There are multiple `Title` properties, perhaps you can be more specific, such as `AutomationRunItems.Case.Title`, `AutomationRunItems.Environment.Title`, `AutomationRunItems.Resolution.Width`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `$parsed` data you can extract all the information you need.

For example to extract the width:

```
echo $parsed.AutomationRunItems.Resolution.Width
```

should print: 1280

I think these are all the fields you need extracted. Note, since you did not specify the output precisely I have simply used comma-delimited strings:

```
$output= ''
$output = $output + $parsed.ScheduleTitle + ','
$output = $output + $parsed.AutomationRunItems.Case.Title + ','
$output = $output + $parsed.AutomationRunItems.Environment.Title + ','
$output = $output + $parsed.AutomationRunItems.Resolution.Width + ','
$output = $output + $parsed.AutomationRunItems.Resolution.Height
```

Should Print: `Resolution Testing,Resolution Test,Se Chrome,1280,1024`

Comment: He already has the JSON in `$parsed`, so he doesn't need to save it to a file. He just needs to reference the right properties, such as you mentioned `$parsed.AutomationRunItems.Resolution.Width`

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it.